# Windows job object can't read clipboard set by other program

Tags: c++, windows, object, jobs

I am trying to make a program runing in a job object context, but after I set the restriction to the job, when I copy something from other program which is not in the job, then go back to my program and try to use ctrl+v or right-click menu paste, the program in the job context will simply paste nothing.

But in other situation, for example when I copy something from my program and paste it in somewhere inside my program or other program it would run normally.

I started study for job object for a few days and this is so weird to me, because I didn't set the restriction of JOB_OBJECT_UILIMIT_WRITECLIPBOARD or JOB_OBJECT_UILIMIT_READCLIPBOARD. Could you please tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks!

My system is Windows 7 64 bit, and here is the code that causes this problem:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

#define exePath L"c:\\windows\\notepad.exe"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hJob = CreateJobObject( NULL , NULL );
    JOBOBJECT_BASIC_UI_RESTRICTIONS jobbuir;
    jobbuir.UIRestrictionsClass  = JOB_OBJECT_UILIMIT_NONE;

    jobbuir.UIRestrictionsClass |= JOB_OBJECT_UILIMIT_DESKTOP;
    jobbuir.UIRestrictionsClass |= JOB_OBJECT_UILIMIT_EXITWINDOWS;
    jobbuir.UIRestrictionsClass |= JOB_OBJECT_UILIMIT_SYSTEMPARAMETERS; 

    SetInformationJobObject(hJob, JobObjectBasicUIRestrictions, &jobbuir, sizeof(jobbuir));

    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    BOOL bResult = CreateProcess(
         exePath, L"" , NULL, NULL, FALSE,
         CREATE_SUSPENDED | CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB |
         CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT | DETACHED_PROCESS , NULL, NULL, &si, &pi
    );
    AssignProcessToJobObject(hJob, pi.hProcess);
    ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    HANDLE h[2];
    h[0]=pi.hProcess;
    h[1]=hJob;

    DWORD dw = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, h, FALSE, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(hJob);
    return 0;
}
```

Blast Xiang

Comment: I eventually solved by using a broker and transfer clipboard data to the process running in the job.